# Is summation linear in a passive membrane?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics, synapses

I am not too sure what it means for summation to be linear? I am running a simulation and as I decrease time for the second EPSP the amplitude decreases. Does summation being linear mean that there is a direct negative linear relationship between delay of onset and amplitude? I also noticed there is no change when I double or triple my conductance value.

I am just not too sure what the relationship is telling me.

Answer (score 1):

For a membrane to satisfy the conditions for linear summation implies that when two EPSPs of amplitude $A$ and $B$ are summed at the integration zone, the resulting output signal will be of amplitude $A+B$. Since the signal [dissipates due to time and length constants](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Rall_model), increasing the delay between the two inputs means that the later input will be dissipated so $A+B$ will be smaller than it would have if the delay was shorter. Under this scenario, inputs $A$ and $B$ are still summed linearly. However, if the delay is shorter than the time constants or the inputs are delivered closer in space than the length constant, then you may get [non-linear summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_(neurophysiology)#Types) since the output signal at the integration zone will be larger than $A+B$.

Have a look here for more information (especially Figure 7):
Silver RA. Neuronal arithmetic. *Nature reviews Neuroscience*. 2010;11(7):474-489. [doi:10.1038/nrn2864](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4750293/).